# Ansible Python API task specific stats

Tags: python, ansible

This is my ansible playbook call

```
playbook_cb = callbacks.PlaybookCallbacks(verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)
stats = callbacks.AggregateStats()
runner_cb = callbacks.PlaybookRunnerCallbacks(stats, verbose=utils.VERBOSITY)
pb = PlayBook(
    playbook=ANS_PLAYBOOK,
    host_list=ANS_INVENTORY,
    callbacks = playbook_cb,
    runner_callbacks = runner_cb,
    stats = runner_cb
)
results = pb.run()
return results
```

and the output that i currently get is

```
{'device': {'unreachable': 0, 'skipped': 7, 'ok': 9, 'changed': 8, 'failures': 0}}
```

That's fairly OK, but i want to get the task-specific stats so that if something fails I can see what and where.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement python CLI that used the ansible python bindings.
I failed because they have change classes, options and import hierarchy between minor versions.

The best source for find an answer for your question is to look inside appropriate `ansible-playbook` binary (every new version is different) and try to find the calls that you should use.

PS:
This is my question with ansible 1.5.4 api 
[How to set vars into ansible inventory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880142/how-to-set-vars-into-ansible-inventory) and what you need at t['failures']  `colorize('failed', t['failures'], None)),`

Also you should check if there is something helpful inside my next code sniplet: 
[How to get all tasks of ansible playbook limit to ansible_os_family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942869/how-to-get-all-tasks-of-ansible-playbook-limit-to-ansible-os-family)